# try and catch executed at the same time

Tags: php

So i have this OOP Login & register system which gives a user the ability to change his/her name.

When a user is pressing "Update" button his/her name is changed in the DB the problem is that tho it changes the name in DB instead of redirecting the user where i want him/her to be redirected i get the error that should appear only when that name couldn't be changed.

<kbd>User.php</kbd>

```
<?php

class User{
private $_db,
        $_data,
        $_sessionName,
        $_cookieName,
        $_isLoggedIn;

public function __construct($user = null){
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
    $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

    if(!$user){
        if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)){
            $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

            if($this->find($user)){
                $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
            } else{
                //process logout
            }
        }
    } else{
        $this->find($user);
    }
}

public function update($fields = array(), $id = null){

    if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()){
        $id = $this->data()->id;
    }

    if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)){
        throw new Exception('There was a problem updating your profile.');
    }
}

public function create($fields = array()){
    if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)){
        throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account');
    }
}

public function find($user = null){
    if($user){
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

        if($data->count()){
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false){
    if(!$username && !$password && $this->exists()){
        Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
    } else{
        $user = $this->find($username);
        if($user){
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)){
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

                if($remember){
                    $hash = Hash::unique();
                    $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

                    if(!$hashCheck->count()){
                        $this->_db->insert('users_session',array(
                            'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                            'hash' => $hash
                        ));
                    } else{
                        $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                    }
                    Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function exists(){
    return(!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
}

public function logout(){
    $this->_db->delete('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

    Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
    Cookie::delete(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
}

public function data(){
    return $this->_data;
}

public function isLoggedIn(){
    return $this->_isLoggedIn;
}
}
```

<kbd>edit-profile.php</kbd>

```
<?php

    $user = new User();
    if(!$user->isLoggedIn()){
        Redirect::to('login');
    }

    if(Input::exists()){
        if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))){

            $validate = new Validate();
            $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                'name' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' => 50
                )
            ));

            if($validation->passed()){

                try{
                    $user->update(array(
                        'name' => Input::get('name')
                    ));

                    Session::flash('flash', 'Your profile has been edited with success!');
                    Redirect::to('flash');

                } catch(Exception $e){
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
            } else{
                foreach($validation->errors() as $error){
                    echo $error . '<br />';
                }
            }

        }
    }

    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->name); ?>">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    </form>
```

I have no clue why that is happening

This is the update() method in my DB.class

```
public function update($table, $id, $fields){
        $set = '';
        $x = 1;

        foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";
            if($x < count($fields)){
                $set .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

        if($this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what is this? `DB::getInstance()` i Mean I know what it is (singleton) but is it a library or something, basically whats the return for update.  That is a lot of static calls  in there....

Comment: I mean on the surface it looks ok, not sure i would do it this way but...

Comment: DB.php is my DB class. i can't add it as a comment appearently... update method is basicly this:

    public function update($table, $id, $fields){
  $set = '';
  $x = 1;

  foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
   $set .= "{$name} = ?";
   if($x < count($fields)){
    $set .= ', ';
   }
   $x++;
  }

  $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

  if($this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

Comment: just for reference you don't need to add whole classes only the relevant bits.  If anything the full code makes it harder to figure out.

Comment: oky :D so then that's the update method from DB class :D

Comment: well that's hard to read, the DB is where the issue probably is without that I im guessing, this looks out of place `if($this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) return true;`  To me that says if there is an error return true.  your update code could be simplified using implode and an array, just saying.

Comment: i edited this question to add the update() method from DB.php where is my DB class :P can you show me how to do the thing you're telling me about? :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your update function

```
public function update($table, $id, $fields){
    $set = '';
    $x = 1;
    foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
        $set .= "{$name} = ?";
        if($x < count($fields)){
            $set .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";
    if($this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Instead do

```
public function update($table, $id, $fields){

    $set = [];

    foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
       $set[] = "{$name} = ?";
    }

    $set = implode(', ', $set);

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = ?";
    $fields[] = $id; //id should always be the last ?
    if($this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also there is the potential for the `table` and `id` and even the keys of `$fields` to be used as a vector for SQL injection.  You may be entering it where ever you use them. But it's possible because you are not checking the table against a white list and anytime you concatenate values into SQL there is the potential for them to be exploited.  All it takes is one mistake, you class should not allow coding errors in other places to compromise it's security.

You can get a list of tables from the database itself.

```
$statement = 'SELECT `TABLE_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` LIKE "'.$database.'"';
```

So when you connect to the DB you could set a list of acceptable tables then check when a table is put in ( with `in_array` or such ).  Just a thought.

It may also be possible to comprise the keys of the `$fields` array, for that you can do something similar to the table. but with this query

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM {table}
```

For example, imagine a post request that has inputs matching your array `$fields`. All someone would have to do is send your server a request with the `SQL Attack` part in the key instead of the value and you are unprotected. Something like this ( don't drop your DB without a backup, feel i should say that.)

```
  $_POST['1=1; DROP DATABASE --'] = true;
```

When you construct your query you would have

```
INSERT INTO table SET 1=1; DROP DATABASE -- = ?, {field} = ? .. rest of query
```

The `--` starts a comment in SQL so nothing after the `--` matter to the DB this prevents an error from happening..  So be careful of just dumping post keys into your SQL  I'm not sure `1=1` would work but they could use a field out of the input list just as easily.  this is just for example purposes.

To me this line

```
   if($this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
        return true;
   }else{
        return false;
   }
```

Says if there is an error return `true` not sure if that is the case as i don't know what `$this->query` or `->error()` is but I imagine `$this->query` must return `$this` or some object that would contain the error.  It's just confusing worded that way.

Comment: O god...ok so thank you for showing me this line  if($this->query($sql, $fields)->error()).... Basicly i forgot to add this logical operator "!"...i just added it and now it works so beautifully. Thank you sooo soo much >:D<

Comment: Sure please take heed of my warnings on SQL Injection, I wrote a similar DB class for PDO using the two queries above, to sanitize the input keys and the table.  As a bonus `SHOW COLUMNS` will tell you what field is the Primary key.

Comment: hmm, i'm using this function to escape inputs: function escape($string){
 return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}. Isn't this going to do the work? :-s

Comment: no, because I am talking about the table and field names.  even then that cleans HTML from it not sql, and they don't need quotes or anything, ie it's easier to exploit the table name part or field names.

Comment: Some day I will have to port my DB class to github, but it's to dependent on other files at the moment.  Anyway, it's past my bed time have to go to work in 4 hours.

Comment: o god :-s. can you explain me a bit more cause i really have no clue how to do this, i've read your answer 1000 times and i still don't know what am i supposed to do X_x(as a note i'm also using a Token class for CSFR protection if that helps :-s) which basicly generates a token for each reafresh of that page that only that page knows...i guess =))

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to fully explain it, you have to check any thing you add to the query like this `INSERT INTO $table` this should be check against a list of table names.  Same with the keys of `$fields`  as in my example someone could make a post to your site like this `$_POST['1=1; DROP DATABASE --'] = true;` which would destroy your Database.  because you use the key as part of the query.  it's very easy to send a request like that.  Prepared statements are good, but that doesn't protect you if you add stuff into the query.

Comment: The stuff you are talking about CSFR and XSS type attacks are different then SQL injection.  This may help explain it better then I can https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp